# Where to get blender with the "New Particle System"

Tags: particles, experimental-features

I was watching this video from Default Cube:
https://youtu.be/EnHdTPd0a4s?t=93

Where he is using the "New Particle System" that is using nodes.

[image]

I downloaded 2.92.0-alpha but it's not there:

[image]

Here is more info about it:

https://developer.blender.org/T73324

I did found this in the youtube comments:

> Before anyone asks: https://developer.blender.org/rBM7254 removed simulation nodes (for now)

My question is, where can I download a branch that has the "New Particle System"?

Comment: Looks like this was the commit where it was removed in favor of geometry nodes: https://github.com/blender/blender/commit/8738a668d8209b41e7554b3711213b43800b3bd4 . I'll see if I can find a build of a recent ancestor...

Comment: Hrm. The storage for old daily builds would probably be spendy. They don't seem to make it easy. Could do a local build of the parent to the above link using these instructions: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender .

Comment: I looked into it, but it's to complex for me. I hope someone can share a old build some day.